# .htaccess test query parameters instead of FilesMatch

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have the following htaccess file:

```
<filesMatch "\.png$">
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Cache-Control "public"
Header set Content-Description "File Transfer"
Header set Content-Disposition "attachment"
Header set Content-Type "image/png"
Header set Content-Transfer-Encoding "binary"
</ifModule>
</filesMatch>
```

I'd like to test the %{QUERY_STRING} instead of performing a filesmatch. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not going to be able to do this using only your htaccess file. You're going to need to write a script or something to set the headers, then map requests to the script using something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^dl=true$
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.png$ /image_dl.php?file=$1.png [L]
```

Then in your image_dl.php script:

```
<?php
header('Cache-Control: public');
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment');
header('Content-Type: image/png');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

$file = $_GET['file'];
header("Content-length: ".filesize($file));  

ob_clean();
flush();
readfile($file); 
?>
```